# О роде глагола при существительном мужского рода

Tags: грамотная-речь, род

Слово "директор" общего рода. Это означает, что глагол, приставленный к нему, может употребляться как в женском, так и в мужском роде. Вопрос: если директор — всё-таки женщина, можно ли по отношению к нему употребить глагол м. р.?

Директор позвал меня.

Answer (score 1):

Но это нелогично. Если Вы знаете, что это женщина, то только ***"директор позвала меня"***

Answer (score 0):

Это допустимо в разговоре с человеком посторонним (посетителем организации и пр.), для которого бесполезна информация о том, что директор — женщина, и которому просто хотят объяснить причину, по которой ему придётся подождать.